# Absolute position in a single dimension

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to absolute position a view using [position()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/position(x:y:)) in a single axis?

For example, I want to absolute position an element's x position but leave the y position as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `.padding(.leading, 100)`. This will make the view have a 100 point gap on the left, but keep the Y position default.